# Deal with memory limit

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have function for export data into csv file :

```
$products = //databse query

foreach($products as $key => $product) {

$products[$key]['example'] = 'example';
                   .
                   .
                   .
}

$csv = new parseCSV();
$csv->output ('products.csv', $products, $labels, $delimiter);
```

Problem is with memory limit, when user hase many records. 
How can I deal with memory limit without increase it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write your csv file line by line, take a look at example here :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: Is it better to create file and then add data or put everything to output ? Or maybe this is doesn't matter ?

Answer (score 0):

Found on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fgetcsv.php#78058) which makes sense to me.

```
<?php 
 $handle = fopen('somefile.csv', 'r'); 
 if ($handle) 
 { 
     set_time_limit(0); 

     //the top line is the field names 
     $fields = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ','); 

     //loop through one row at a time 
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ',')) !== FALSE) 
     { 
         $data = array_combine($fields, $data); 
     } 

     fclose($handle); 
 } 
?>
```

Comment: Oh wait, you're looking for a way to write CSV instead of reading from it?

Answer (score 0):

Split your list in chunks and name them "products_x.csv" by using a for loop

```
$start = isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : 0;
for ( $i=$start; $i < $start + $MAX; $i++) {
    // add products to csv
}
// csv output and download
```